# Bluemix SSO for Mobile Web Services

Tags: ios, node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am working on a native iOS application which will retrieve a web service that I will create on a Bluemix Liberty or node.js application. The challenge I have is that it needs to be secured by Single Sign On or oAuth. I need the provider to be IBM ID. I have implemented SSO (W3) on Liberty previously for a web based application but want to know if it is possible to use the same approach (albeit WWW) for protecting the web services for my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bluemix provides the [Single Sign On](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted) service. It allows you to use different types of identity providers,  but it fully supports only integration with W3 ID for now. SSO with IBM ID worked with the previous version of the service, that is currently deprecated. [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27044519) you can find documentation for that version.

Comment: Thanks Umberto, unfortunately I can't use the old version of the service and so can't use Bluemix for this project.